# Java opencv inRange thresholding function makes my image into three different images?

Tags: java, c++, swing, opencv

I am using java opencv and this is the line that I am executing.

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(originalImage, hsvImage, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);
Core.inRange(hsvImage, low, high, thresholdImage);
```

low and high are some Scalar values(of size 3 each). So my original image as you can see is of 3 channels, but my `thresholdImage` has only one channel, why? As a result of this, when I try to display `thresholdImage`, I get three small images in my `JFrame`. How to fix this?

Comment: I think the question is quite complete. SO's policy needs questions that are specific and I think this question is quite specific and I tend to keep my questions as specific as possible without unnecessary information. Please refer to my answer as I think I have figured it out. If I am wrong, please do correct me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that `Core.inRange` changes the second argument, which is a `Mat`, to a single channel image. So in order to get 3 channels, I needed to use `Imgproc.cvtColor` function to re-convert it back to 3 channels.